# 10% in Group A, and 20% in Group B vs. 10% and 20% in Group A and Group B, respectively

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

when someone needs to describe percentages in each group, which is more common to describe numbers in each group?

1. 10% in Group A, and 20% in Group B.
2. 10% and 20% in Group A and Group B, respectively.

If there is any differences in nuances between them, I will appreciate if you would let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a matter of opinion, but option 1 seems clearer and therefore preferable. ("Respectively" doesn't add any elegance or pretentiousness, in my opinion, unless you're trying to communicate with high school dropouts.)

Option 2 might be preferable if you have a list of items that have a predictable order. For example:

> Spring, Summer, Fall, and Winter have average rainfalls of 14.5", 22", 8.25", and 11.5", respectively.

Otherwise, I think #1 is the better way to go.